# TensorFlow classifier prediction script always outputs zero

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, neural-network, regression

I have created a script to evaluate a TensorFlow convolutional neural network. It loads some images and does some simple preprocessing:

```
def main(argv):
    classifier = import_model()
    for path in argv[1:]:
        image_reversed = imread(path).astype(np.float32)
        image_unlayered = np.transpose(image_reversed, (1, 0, 2))
        image = np.reshape(image_unlayered, [1, -1, 480, 3])
        angle = infer_steering_angle(classifier, image)
        print("Steering angle %f for image %s." % (angle, path))
```

It imports the model using a network structure function in another file that has been verified to at least mostly work and is used to train a network:

```
def import_model():
    # Load estimator
    classifier = learn.Estimator(
        model_fn=cnn_model_fn,
        model_dir="/tmp/network2"
    )
    return classifier
```

and finally, it uses the `Estimator.predict` function to pass the single image to the network, overriding the default `batch_size` of 10 and setting it to 1. It returns a tensor with a single element, which should correspond to the steering angle (this is an end-to-end autonomous driving regression problem).

```
def infer_steering_angle(classifier, image):
    output = classifier.predict(
        x=image,
        batch_size=1
    )
    for angle in output:
        return angle
```

The problem is, it *always* outputs 0.0 for the steering angle. I've looked over all of this several times, and the only thing I can  think of is that I'm misunderstanding the `Estimator.predict` function. It's rather poorly documented, in that it lacks concrete examples of how it should be used. Does anybody notice anything wrong with how I'm formatting the input or parsing the output?

UPDATE:

I tried putting this code right in the training file, so the importing can't be the problem. I'm starting to become suspicious it's a problem with the model itself. The code is at https://hastebin.com/rakulonebu.py.

Comment: Stupid question, but did you actually train the model?

Comment: @MadWombat Yes, I trained the model in that folder, using the `cnn-model-fn` definition script which is here: https://hastebin.com/rakulonebu.py

Comment: Did you get good evaluation results from training? Does your training data contain examples where steering angle is not 0?

Comment: @MadWombat No, the model was actually performing quite crappily, and that was half of the problem. I couldn't figure out how to evaluate it. But the loss function was at least _changing_, and converging-ish on something. So I tried it after just 1 iteration of changing, where the outputs should be pretty close to random, but no dice. I just want some non-zero value. I can troubleshoot it from there.

Comment: Are you using the estimator from tf.contrib.learn or from tf.estimator?

Comment: @MadWombat tf.contrib.learn, as per this tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers

Comment: It seems that the signature for the predict() method changed somewhat recently. Here is a short quote from the docs

"SOME ARGUMENTS ARE DEPRECATED. They will be removed after 2016-12-01. Instructions for updating: Estimator is decoupled from Scikit Learn interface by moving into separate class SKCompat. Arguments x, y and batch_size are only available in the SKCompat class, Estimator will only accept input_fn."

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/Estimator#predict

Comment: @MadWombat It says the same thing for the Estimator.fit function, but it still runs as of TF 1.2. Maybe they forgot to remove it? I could never figure out how to get an `input_fn` working.

Comment: Try to use the SKCompat instead of Estimator

Comment: @MadWombat Did, no dice.

Comment: @MadWombat trying the `input_fn` thing now.

Comment: It might actually be that this is what your network learned. That giving zero all the time minimized the loss function :)

Comment: @MadWombat I thought of that. I thought removing regularization had solved it, but that turned out not to be the case.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44932870/trained-tensorflow-model-always-outputs-zero

Comment: @MadWombat Moreover, that's why I tested after one iteration, so it wouldn't have time to optimize like that.

Comment: What if you skip the loading from directory completely, just use a freshly initialized model? It should use some uniform distribution for weights, so technically it should not be all zeroes.

Comment: @MadWombat Yeah, I'll give that a try too, although running it after just one iteration of training _should_ have had a similar result. Thanks so much for the ideas!

Comment: @MadWombat I ended up switching to Keras, and had the same problem, but I figured it out. It was the activation function. https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/3687